# Norm of a basis vector

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $e_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$. Does $\|e_i\|=1$ for every norm $\|\cdot\|$?
If not, does anyone has a counter-example?

Comment: Yes. Define $\|e_i\|=2.$

Comment: If $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on a vector space, then so is $\alpha\|\cdot\|$ for any $\alpha>0$. So the answer to your first question is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm $$\|(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n)\| = 2\cdot \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2+\cdots +x_n^2}$$ is one such example.